# Edit last multidimensional array item

Tags: php

I need to edit the last item in a multidimensional array

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [column] => Country
        [operator] => =
        [value] => 2
        [total] => 0
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [column] => State
        [operator] => =
        [value] => 1
        [total] => 0
    )

)
```

Only edit the `total` field of the last array

```
$count = count( $array);
$ultimaChave[$count]['total'] = 55;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP uses zero based indices, so you simply need to grab the length of the array minus one:

```
$count = count($array);
$array[$count-1]['total'] = 55;
```